# Using switch statement to make a simple calculator

Tags: c, switch-statement, calculator

I created a program of using 'switch' statement to make a simple calculator. If I first take the integer output & then the operator output, the value of b is always shown '0'. (the code is given here) However, if I first take the operator output, the program works just fine. What may be the reason for this? Thanks.

```
int a;
int b;
char sign;

printf("Enter two required integers: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
scanf("%d", &b);

printf("Enter the operator(+ or - or * or /): ");
scanf(" %s", &sign);


switch(sign){

    case '+': printf("The summation of %d and %d is %d", a,b, a+b);
              break;

    case '-': printf("The subtraction of %d and %d is %d", a,b, a-b);
              break;

    case '*': printf("The product of %d and %d is %d", a,b, a*b);
              break;

    case '/': printf("The division of %d and %d is %d", a,b, a/b);
              break;

    default: printf("Enter the right operator noob!");
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 5):

```
scanf(" %s", &sign);
```

this is not correct. `sign` is `char` so it can only store 1 character, but you are trying to read a string which would need more than 1 characters so that would override the memory.

Rather use

```
scanf(" %c", &sign);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic question. You should keep in mind that a **char** can contain a single character from the keyboard. On the other hand, when you do character variable input or output, you should use %c for this purpose. On the other hand, we know, **a string is built with multiple character combination**. String variable is declared with char

> variable[size];

And for string input or output, you need to use %s. As you used no 'string' here, **you need to replace %s with %c** and that should solve your issue!